# Запуск приложения с MotionLayout на API ниже 21

Tags: android

Исходя из руководства для этого виджета, должен быть API 21+ , что будет, если приложение с данным виджетом MotionLayout будет запущено скажем на девайсе с API 17?

Большая просьба, если минусите вопрос, указывайте причину, это позволит улучшать качество задаваемых вопросов

Comment: Оно либо упадёт, либо отобразит к-л странную разметку или не будет анимация работать. Надо запускать и проверять. Но скорее всего приложение просто не соберётся с указанием минимального API меньше 21. Т.е. поставить просто не получится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как то можно это обработать? Например при апи 21+ этот лэйаут при ниже другой? И еще вопрос, как то можно посмотреть каков процент работы на определенном апи, чтобы знать сколько я теряю пользователей

Comment: В первую очередь надо просто взять девайс/эмулятор и запустить. Обойти можно да, с помощью разной разметки для разных версий API. Правда, в теории может быть так, что либа, требующая 21 API как минимальный не будет давать вам собрать проект с меньшим минимальным API. В таком случае надо будет создавать обденые варианты сборки с этой библиотекой и без неё. Google Play, вроде, разрешает выкладывать разные APK для разных девайсов/версий ОС. Посмотреть же статистику юзеров по версиям ОС можно в консоли разработчика или в системе аналитики сторонней, если у вас какая-то в приложение встроена.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ок большое спасибо за совет. УДачи